# discover when the element is inserted to the std::map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dictionary

My program is  inserting (with [] operator]) some data[addresses] into the std::map. I can track inserting of 137 elements.They all are inserted with valid values.

In some stage I iterate the map and try to do some manipulation with the values[addresses]
I`ve set a breakpoint right before I start  to iterate the map.
When I check the map in debugger I still see 137 elements.But when I iterate it until the

`iterator != map.end` I discover ,that the map has 138 values - the last one is illegal.

I need to find a way to detect when this last problematic value is inserted.I use VS 2010.

Thank you

Comment: So, where do you call `insert`?  Do you use `operator[]`?  Show some code.

Comment: I I use [] operator.It is big company`s project.I can`t show the code

Comment: If you use `operator[]` you have to be sure that you want to insert a value for that key, since it returns a reference.  It will happily insert a value for you, and depending our your value type it's easy to get garbage in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try placing conditional breakpoints in the insertion functions of `std::map`

For me (using VC10), the appropriate places are line 755 (for `std::map::insert`) and line 767 (for `std::map::operator[]`) of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xtree

You can add a condition on each breakpoint of `_Mysize == 137` to catch the insertion which increases the `map` size to 138.

The most likely culprit is probably the [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) since it's easy to mistakenly think of this as an accessor only.

Answer (score 6):

You could, just for debugging, replace the `std::map` with a wrapper class that hides the `std::map::insert` member function with one that prints out debug information.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

template<class Key, 
         class Value, 
         class Compare = std::less<Key>, 
         class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, Value>>>
struct wrap_map : std::map<Key, Value, Compare, Allocator>
{
  typedef std::map<Key, Value, Compare, Allocator> base_type;

  std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value )
  {
    std::cout << "Inserted: [" << value.first << "] : " << value.second << std::endl;
    return base_type::insert( value );
  }
};

int main()
{
  wrap_map<int, std::string> mymap;

  mymap.insert( std::make_pair( 10, std::string( "Hello, World!" ) ) );
  std::cout << mymap[10] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Inserted: [10] : Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```

You'll have to create overloads for any other overloads of [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) that you're using in your code, and for `std::map::operator[]` if you use that to insert elements into the map.

You could also print out macros such as `__LINE__` to indicate where the insertion is happening.

Note that `std::map` does not have a virtual destructor, so if you're dynamically allocating the map, then using this approach could lead to undefined behavior unless you replace the type name everywhere with `wrap_map`.