# The end of std::map is shifted

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dictionary, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [discover when the element is inserted to the std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221648/discover-when-the-element-is-inserted-to-the-stdmap)

I track inserting of 137 elements in to the map When I check using VS2010 debugger the size of map I get indeed 137.Using printf I print all elements of the map by

```
(it = map.begin();it !=map.end();++it) {
   printf ("%x",it->second);
}
```

As a result 137 values are printed.
After that my program continues to execute.And near the end of execution I need to treat the values of the map.

I once more check with debugger that it has 137 elements but when I print all of them as previously I get 138 values printed,when the last one is invalid value.

I need to understand how/when it happens and what causes `map.end()` to be shifted.

Comment: Show us the code between the two "printings"

Comment: @chris - yes.The values are addresses

Comment: Are you using `operator[]` needlessly?

Comment: @Grzegorz - I insert addresses and I know that the way they look like .the last value is different.Also based on size i know that I need 137 values to be printed,not 138

Comment: @KirilKirov >>Show us the code between the two "printings" - it is a big industrial project I can`t show the code

Comment: Is it something like `while (map[i++] != NULL)`?

Comment: Why don't you debug it and find out where this extra element comes from?

Comment: Why ask the same question twice?

Comment: @tenfour - can you advse me how to debug it correctly ?All inserts i see inser valid value.I can`t figure out when incorrect value is inserted and why the size remains unchanged

Comment: @GManNickG - this question is slightly differnt(I agrry it is the same topic)

Comment: I don't see how this question is different. Either way, unless you post some code that reproduces the problem nobody can answer either question.

Comment: @Blastfurnace - it is a user mode driver project with many code lines.It is impossible to paste it here

Comment: Can you pare the code down to a minimal example that reproduces the problem? Your prose description of the problem is insufficient to determine what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the code it is hard to tell. We can guess.
I suggest you rewrite operator that adds to your map, and after each adding check what is the size of your map. When the size is > 137 cause your program to GPF (or call function that will cause debugger to break.) Run your program in debugger, and bingo, the stack trace will tell you where you have the problem.